# How to check this start_date>check_date in django ORM filter?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

How to check this start_date>check_date in django ORM filter?

```
check_date = request.GET.get('start_date')

    qs = Test.objects.values('opinion').annotate(
        count=Count('opinion'),
        dcount=Count('opin_id',
                     distinct=True)).filter(start_date__gte='check_date').order_by("count")
```

here how can I check the`start_date` with `check_date`. This method is not working`filter(start_date__gte='check_date')`
`filter(start_date__gte=check_date)` also not working

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: no errors. But not getting the result which is greater than the provided date,

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotation around you check_date in your filter

```
filter(start_date__gte=check_date)
```

Comment: Why are you comparing the same value in your filter.with this `check_date=request.GET.get('start_date')` you are returning the same value of `start_date` to the `check_date` so check_date will never be greater than `start_date` @MaqboolThoufeeqT

Comment: No. It's actually ```start_name``` inside ```filter``` is a field in the Module. But the start_date in request is the date which we are passing from UI